# How do I use Azure AD to connect to Azure SQL in my web app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I want to write a tool that uses a users's own Azure AD credentials to run queries against an Azure SQL database.  Is that possible?  I can setup my own app for authentication, but importantly I want the users to be able to enter free-form queries and use their own credentials when executing the SQL, not the permissions associated with my application.

Answer (score 1):

AS far as I known, C# provides ActiveDirectoryInteractive mode that can be used to connect to Azure SQL Database. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to implement the scenario you have described. Apart from the obvious Azure SQL Server and Web Application/API setup, there are two main things to highlight for Authentication.

**Authentication Highlights**

- From Azure Active Directory standpoint, your application registration can make use of "Delegated Permissions" for Azure SQL, so that application can access database on behalf of signed-in user (instead of using SQL user from connection string or application's permissions).
- Once you have authenticated the user to your web application using Azure AD and have the authentication token available in your web application/API, now make use of the OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow [described here on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow), to make sure you Web Application/API accesses the database.

I am giving more detailed steps and links to a blog from MS playground that does something very similar below.

**Detailed Steps**

1. Enable Azure Active Directory Authentication for Azure SQL Server
2. Add Azure Active Directory Users with appropriate role/permissions
3. Register your web application/API to Azure Active Directory ([Registering application with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app))
4. For "Required Permissions" of your Application, Add and select

   a. Azure Portal > Azure AD > App Registrations > Your App Registration

   [image]

   b. Select "Azure SQL Database"

   [image]

   c. Select "Delegated Permissions" > "Azure SQL DB and Data Warehouse"

   [image]
5. User authenticates to your Web Application/API using Azure AD. This can be directly to your web application (that calls Azure SQL Database), or through a client application that calls into your Web API (if have separate front end and API.. then API application makes calls to Azure SQL Database).
6. Now that your web application/API has Azure AD Access token available to it, make use of On-behalf-of flow to call the Azure SQL Database, on behalf of the signed in user. This will utilize the delegated permissions from Azure AD that we setup earlier. [Sample code for On-behalf-Of flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Service-to-service-calls-on-behalf-of-the-user)

**Blog Post with more details**

This is a blog post from MSFT playground, which does something similar. There are 3 parts to it. I am sharing the 2nd one which is most important. You can follow the other 2 as well as you see fit.

[Part 2 – Azure API Application to query the Azure SQL Database](https://msftplayground.com/2017/05/part-2-azure-api-application-to-query-the-azure-sql-database/)